# Gulp task React Invalid mapping error

Tags: reactjs, browserify

We are seeing the following error when running gulp. It complains about a specific JSX file. DrugsModalDialog.jsx. Any comments / thoughts / pointers will be helpful.

> C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\node_m
>   odules\combine-source-map\node_modules\inline-source-map\node_modules\source-map
>   \lib\source-map\source-map-generator.js:275
>           throw new Error('Invalid mapping: ' + JSON.stringify({
>           ^
>
> Error: Invalid mapping:
>   {"generated":{"line":91123,"column":20},"source":"DrugsM
>   odalDialog.jsx","original":{},"name":null}
>       at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (C:\testUI\cdicm
>   s-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-
>   source-map\node_modules\inline-source-map\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map
>   \source-map-generator.js:275:15)
>       at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\no
>   de_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-source-map\
>   node_modules\inline-source-map\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-map
>   -generator.js:105:14)
>       at C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack
>   \node_modules\combine-source-map\node_modules\inline-source-map\index.js:40:15
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Generator.addMappings (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\no
>   de_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-source-map\node_modules\inline-sour
>   ce-map\index.js:38:12)
>       at Combiner._addExistingMap (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify
>   \node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-source-map\index.js:33:18)
>       at Combiner.addFile (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
>   dules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-source-map\index.js:58:12)
>       at Transform.write [as _transform] (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\bro
>   wserify\node_modules\browser-pack\index.js:63:23)
>       at Transform._read (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_mod
>   ules\browser-pack\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream
>   _transform.js:184:10)
>       at Transform._write (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
>   dules\browser-pack\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_strea
>   m_transform.js:172:12)
>       at doWrite (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\bro
>   wser-pack\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writabl
>   e.js:237:10)
>       at writeOrBuffer (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify\node_modul
>   es\browser-pack\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_w ritable.js:227:5)
>       at Transform.Writable.write (C:\testUI\cdicms-adr-ui\node_modules\browserify
>   \node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\li
>   b_stream_writable.js:194:11)

Here is the DrugModalDialog.jsx code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Modal, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class DrugsModalDialog extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        }
        this.open = this.open.bind(this);
        this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }

    close() {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    }

    open() {
        console.log("open called");
        this.props.getDrugList();
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }

    render() {

    var createADRRow = function(item) {
            return (
                <tr key={item.name}>
                    <td>{item.drug}</td>
                </tr>
    );}

    var modalBody;
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        modalBody = <span>Loading...</span>
    } else if (this.props.drugs.length == 0) {
        modalBody = <span>No drugs found</span>
    } else {
        modalBody = <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody>{this.props.drugs.map(createADRRow,this)}</tbody>
        </table>;
    }

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'inline'}}>
         <input style={{position: 'relative', marginLeft: '15px'}}type="button" value="View Drugs" name="viewDrugs"
            className="btn btn-default pull-right" onClick={this.open}/>
            <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close} bsSize="sm">
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>Drugs</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                {modalBody}
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Any additional flags to debug this browserify error (which line in the JSX file) is highly appreciated.

Some additional information. We have gulpfile task setup as below.

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return browserify({entries: './src/main.jsx', extensions: ['.jsx'], debug: true})
    .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
    .transform(envify({
      HOST_PORT: detectHostPort()
    }))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

If I do `debug : false` then the issue is not happening. There is obviously issues related to generating source maps.

Comment: The issue got resolved after upgrading browserify